# Why does PostgreSQL throw "FULL JOIN is only supported with merge-joinable or hash-joinable join conditions"

Tags: postgresql, join

Trying to join 2 tables with an OR condition like this:

```
FULL JOIN table1
     ON (replace(split_part(table1.contract_award_number::text, ' '::text, 2), '-'::text, ''::text)) = table2.contract_award_id 

     OR (btrim(replace(table1.solicitation_number::text, '-'::text, ''::text))) = table2.solicitation_id
```

But Postgresql is barking at me with:

```
FULL JOIN is only supported with merge-joinable or hash-joinable join conditions
```

What gives? For some reason if I add the condition:

```
WHERE table1.solicitation_number::text ~~ '%%'::text
```

the error doesn't occur, but I suspect this is fouling up the FULL JOIN result.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20060313104028.GB6714%40svana.org

Comment: It is possible to simulate a full outer join as a union of two joins.

Comment: hmm interesting... wouldn't this omit the results that don't join though?

Comment: If you post your full query I can give you a workaround.

Comment: SELECT column1, column2, column3
  
   FROM fpds_opportunities fpds
     FULL JOIN fbo_all_opportunity_detail fbo 
     ON replace(split_part(fbo.contract_award_number::text, ' '::text, 2), '-'::text, ''::text) = fpds.contract_award_id 
     
     OR btrim(replace(fbo.solicitation_number::text, '-'::text, ''::text)) = fpds.solicitation_id
  WHERE AND (fpds.base_and_all_options_value::numeric > 20000::numeric OR fpds.base_and_all_options_value IS NULL);

Comment: Sorry, had to cut it down to get it into the StackOverflow character limit

Comment: The problem with the UNION ALL join method is that it doesn't account for the OR condition in the join (which is what is causing the error in the first place). I'm thinking there might be a way to run 2 joins and union then dedupe?

Comment: I attempted an answer below.  I think we can workaround the ugly join condition because the `fpds_opportunities` table actually uses direct single columns for the join logic.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It should be possible to emulate any full outer join between two tables using the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM t1
RIGHT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t1.id IS NULL
```

The first half of the union obtains the records unique to the first table, along with all overlapping records.  The second half of the union obtains records particular to the second table only.  Applying this pattern to your query gives:

```
SELECT column1, column2, column3
FROM fpds_opportunities fpds
LEFT JOIN fbo_all_opportunity_detail fbo
    ON replace(split_part(fbo.contract_award_number::text, ' '::text, 2), 
               '-'::text, ''::text) = fpds.contract_award_id OR
       btrim(replace(fbo.solicitation_number::text, '-'::text, ''::text)) = fpds.solicitation_id
UNION ALL
SELECT column1, column2, column3
FROM fpds_opportunities fpds
RIGHT JOIN fbo_all_opportunity_detail fbo
    ON replace(split_part(fbo.contract_award_number::text, ' '::text, 2), 
               '-'::text, ''::text) = fpds.contract_award_id OR
       btrim(replace(fbo.solicitation_number::text, '-'::text, ''::text)) = fpds.solicitation_id
WHERE
    fpds.contract_award_id IS NULL AND fdps.solicitation_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: in your fist query it should be `UNION`, not `UNION ALL`, shouldn't it?

Like


```sql
SELECT * FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM t1
RIGHT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t1.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

You could precompute the ugly strings in a subquery (or CTE), and JOIN with that. (this also seems handy for building & testing the query; you never get these string-things right te first time ...)

---

```
SELECT ...
FROM table2
FULL JOIN (
        SELECT *
        , replace(split_part(table1.contract_award_number::text, ' '::text, 2), '-'::text, ''::text) AS xca
        , btrim(replace(table1.solicitation_number::text, '-'::text, ''::text)) AS xsa
        FROM table1
        ) AS t1
                ON table2.contract_award_id = t1.xca
                OR table2.solicitation_id = t1.xsa
        ;
```